# Share a dictionary betweeen multiple live threads

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, multiprocessing

I have a Python (2.7) application in which I run multiple threads. Now I would like to update a dictionary in my child thread and use its updated contents in my mother thread without using  join(). Can I do this? I do not want to wait until my child has terminated to use the dictionary's data in my mother thread.

How can I do this?

Comment: I suspect the answer to this depends on what exactly you're putting in the dictionary and how you're accessing it. Dictionary actions are generally thread safe (meaning that the dictionary is always intact, never partly updated due to a thread switch), but that doesn't necessarily means that your two threads will see the right data without any synchronization. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Also, are you using threads, or processes? Your text says threads, but your tags say multiprocessing.

Comment: @Blckknght Processes to avoid the GIL to block execution of concurrent threads.

Comment: @Blckknght I store an array of MAC addresses as keys and TDMN slots per mac address as value in the dictionary. I download the info from the web in a separate process to not interrupt my working process. I have to sync the list of member macs with the cloud every 600 seconds (sat the least).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [threading module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) or the [thread module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html#module-thread).

Here's an example using the thread module:

```
import thread

d = dict()
m = thread.allocate_lock()

def foo():
    m.acquire_lock()
    print(d['key'])

def bar():
    d['key'] = 'value'
    m.release_lock()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    m.acquire_lock()
    t1 = thread.start_new_thread(foo,())
    t2 = thread.start_new_thread(bar,())
```

This illustrates how locks can synchronize thread access to shared resources: as long as `m` is locked, `foo` is waiting to acquire it; meanwhile, `bar` updates the dictionary and releases the lock; only then does `foo` acquire the lock and continues. No joins.

(Of course, this is not how you should write multithreaded code...)

### EDIT

If you have to use processes, you can find similar functionality in the [multiprocessing module](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html).

Here's an example:

```
import multiprocessing

def foo(m, d):
    m.acquire()
    print(d['key'])

def bar(m, d):
    d['key'] = 'value'
    m.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()

    m = multiprocessing.Lock()
    m.acquire()

    d = manager.dict()

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo, args=(m, d))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=bar, args=(m, d))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
```

The `Lock` allows process synchronization, and the `Manager` allows resource sharing for compound types like lists and dictionaries.

Comment: @Dan_Gittik No, I cannot use multiple threads because the GIL blocks execution of multiple threads at the same time. I have to use multiple processes if I want real concurrency - and that is what I need.

Comment: I updated my answer to address both cases. Note that to run my examples you would have to stall the main thread/process with `time.sleep()` or `.join()` so it does not terminate before its children.

Comment: `thread` module had been deprecated by `threading` module since 2005.

Comment: @cerr: GIL is released on IO i.e., your worker and downloading threads can run in parallel. btw, even if GIL were not released the threads would still run concurrently (though without any performance advantages i.e., multiple CPUs won't be utilized in this case).

Comment: Could you refer me a document where it says the `thread` module is deprecated in Python 2.7? As far as I know, it was marked as obsolete and renamed to `_thread` only in Python 3.x... Anyway, it's simpler and clearer than the `threading` module, which is an advantage in educational examples, so I see don't see a reason to down-vote my answer.